# Prove that if $\rho(A)<1 \implies \frac 1{I_n - A} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}A^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Prove that if $\rho(A)<1 \implies \frac 1{I_n - A} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}A^k$.

My attempt:

Well if $\rho(A) < 1\implies |\lambda_{max}|<1$, but $A$ can be rewritten as: $$A=PDP^{-1}$$

Where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the corresponding eigenvalues. Then

$$A^k=PD^kP^{-1}$$

But if $|\lambda_{max}|<1$ then $|\lambda(A)|<1 \implies |\lambda(A)|^k<1$ so:

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}D^k=O_n$$

Then the series must converge like that.

Comment: Remember that from the fact that $a_k$ converges to zero it **does not** follow that the series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ is convergent. You must use a subtler argument.

Comment: Which argument?

Comment: [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your attempt is correct partially.

Missing argument:

Partial sums are $I+A+A^2+...+A^n$, now we see that,
$$(I-A)(I+A+A^2+...+A^n)=I-A^{n+1}$$
But $A^{n+1}\longrightarrow O_n$,
$$\Longrightarrow (I-A)(I+A+A^2+...)=I$$
Hence the result.

Hope it helps:)